# Single element metallic glass?

Tags: material-science

Metallic glass aka amorphous metal is as the name suggest,a metal alloy that instead of crytalline structure have random amorphous structure,this gives the material unique properties.

The key factor is the extremly rapid cooling needed to "freeze" the atoms before they can organize into ordered crystalline form.Every amorphous material I ever read about was alloy of some sort,it always contained atleast two or more elements.

Using two or more elements is to allow for less rapid cooling to make the material amorphous.It have to do with atom radius,the radius of various elements needs to be significantly different.This makes it harder for atoms to organize into crystalline form.

My question is this : is it possible to create single element amorphous metal? I understand it would probably require even higher cooling rate values than already extreme that is required for the multi element alloys but is it even possible? Or is it such that no matter what super high cooling rate is achieved,single elememt amorphous metal will never be created?

Comment: Amorphous tungsten is mentioned in the literature.

Comment: As is [amorphous copper via ion bombardment](http://www.anu.edu.au/CSEM/newsletters/2006/MMFeb06.pdf).